# How to create a field of auto generated document ID itself?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a field of the ID of the document which inherited that field.

```
val fStore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                val currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
                val post = Post(title, description , publisherId = currentUserId)
                fStore.collection("Posts")
                        .add(post)
                        .addOnSuccessListener{
                         Toast("Your post has been uploaded successfully.")
                        }
```

As in the above code, I made a field of `currentUserId` as `publisherId`,
in other words:

[image: example of firestore]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can solve this problem. One would be to use `currentUserId` as the key of the document and then use `set()` instead of `add()`:

```
val fStore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val post = Post(title, description , publisherId = currentUserId)
fStore.collection("Posts")
        .document(currentUserId)
        .set(post)
        .addOnSuccessListener{
            Toast("Your post has been uploaded successfully.")
        }
```

This is a more common solution, as you are using as the key of the document the user ID that comes from the authentication process and not a random key. The second option that you have is to use the id that is generated by Firestore:

```
val fStore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val key = fStore.collection("Posts").document().id;
val post = Post(title, description , publisherId = key)
fStore.collection("Posts")
        .document(key)
        .set(post)
        .addOnSuccessListener{
            Toast("Your post has been uploaded successfully.")
        }
```

In both cases, to have the same value for the document id and for the `publisherId`, you should use set() and **not** add(), because add() it always generates a random id each time is called.

**Edit:**

`set()` does the exact same thing as `add()` does, the only difference is that you need to know the id before you actually use it. So in your case, you should then use the second solution.

If you only want to add the post ID as a property within your document, then you should change your `Post` class by adding another field named `postId`. Now when you want to create a new `Post` object and add it to your database, use the following lines of code:

```
val fStore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val key = fStore.collection("Posts").document().id;
val post = Post(title, description , publisherId = key, postId) //postId added
fStore.collection("Posts")
        .document(key)
        .set(post)
        .addOnSuccessListener{
            Toast("Your post has been uploaded successfully.")
        }
```

See, I have passed to the constructor, the value of the document ID, which is actually the post ID. Now, every time you add a new post, you'll always have the post ID as a property of your document.

Comment: Alex i am using add for making so many unique Id for different posts and i am storing currentUserId  as publisherId because when i retrieve them in a recyclerview then i get the user information in that post by using publisherId , if i use currentUserId at that time it will fetch the info of the user who is logged in. And i want to retrive the post with the id of post so this is why i question this. If there is any other way of doing this then please tell me .

Comment: Yes, there is a way of doing that. I understood now, so please see my updated answer and tell me if it works.

Comment: Thank You so much, You are Genius :D. please check out my other question related to firestore [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61520416/11841294)

Comment: You're very welcome. I see, you already have an excellent answer. Cheers ;)